# Angular 2.0 Startup

Tags: angularjs, angular

I'm new to angular 2.0.  Actually I'm blocked by referencing the angular related resources.

As a beginner, I would like to know which js file to reference (compiled TypeScript) in Index.html to start manipulating with Angular Js 2.0.

In the tutorial of http://angular.io I noticed several references below but I'm not sure which one shall I use in my own project.  Seems none of the reference below related with Angular by looking at the names.  I'm really confused now.

```
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/zone.js@0.6.12?main=browser"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/reflect-metadata@0.1.3"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/systemjs@0.19.27/dist/system.src.js"></script>

<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
```

Comment: Angular relies on libraries that don't have angular in their name. There is nothing wrong with that: they don't reinvent the wheel, or they provide libraries that can be used outside of the context of Angular2. That is true of any framework written in any language that has the concept of libraries.

Comment: As @JB said you don't need to manipulate the libraries in which angular depends unless you are doing some extraordinary stuff.  And by the way what do you mean by I'm blocked by referencing angular related resources?

Comment: The difficulty I got is what to put in index.html so as to use Angular JS 2.0.
I got my own web server & I got index.html.  I need to figure out how to reference Angular Js 2.0 in my web page.

Comment: And, what's the problem in following the official documentation guidelines. What makes you think you need something other than what the documentation says?

Comment: I'd suggest you create and build using https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

Comment: Hi @JBNizet, the problem to me is that the documentation doesn't make it clear about what is the basic js files that I should reference in the Index.html.  It just said that install node js and use npm to install some packages.  I already have my Web Server, and I just need the reference to the Angular JS 2.0 in the index.html.  Just like the reference to JQuery.

Comment: No, you don't just need that. You need the files that the documentation says you should add. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#!#index